# I need to deploy on codebuild in a Different Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying do a deploy in Ohio from São Paulo, I config the buildspec and the conf on .elasticbeanstalk to set a variable to received us-east as parameter.
I did many tryings to do this work but always the error "EXIT STATUS 4" show. This is my last attempt

COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: eb deploy Logoneagendamento-teste --region us-east-2. Reason: exit status 4

And the buildspec.yml is as follows

```
version: 0.2 
phases: 
    install: 
        runtime-versions: 
            java: corretto8 
        commands: 
         - pip install --upgrade awsebcli awscli 
    build: 
        commands: 
         - echo Iniciando build... 
         - mvn package 
         - echo eb list --region 
         - eb list --region us-east-2 
         - echo Inciando deploy 
         - eb deploy $DEPLOY_ENV -r $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        
      post_build: 
        commands: 
        #- command 
        #- command artifacts: files: - 'target/LogOne-Agendamento.jar' 
        # - location #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d) discard-paths: yes –
```

Comment: Is eb available in the machine you are using? Can you share your buildspec.yml and the entire log here?

Comment: This is the log @Rengas: [Container] 2021/05/12 18:37:17 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: eb deploy Logoneagendamento-teste --region us-east-2. Reason: exit status 4

Comment: And the code: 
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
    commands:
       - pip install --upgrade awsebcli awscli
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Iniciando build...
      - mvn package
   
      - echo eb list --region
      - eb list --region us-east-2

      - echo Inciando deploy 
      - eb deploy $DEPLOY_ENV -r $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    
  post_build:
    commands:
      #- command
      #- command
artifacts:
  files:
      - 'target/LogOne-Agendamento.jar'
    # - location
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  discard-paths: yes

Comment: Did you set the IAM role and policy for codebuild to deploy to eb?

Comment: Yes @Rengas, the politics are apply

Comment: Make sure there is no whitespace in the Environmental variable values.